# Activites overview stops the whole system

Tags: gnome, 20.04, freeze, activities-overview

First look at the images to understand what happens

(if anybody can tell me how to upload a video here than it will be much better)

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the story is like this I clicked on the group then click outside the group to close it and then the system got stop.

**Now what happens when it stops?**:- I can use a mouse but mouse clicks don't work also keyboard doesn't work.

**So ultimately I have to force shut down my laptop.**

**How often does this happen?**:- probably depends on background task i.e., if I am using a heavy application like android-studio then it happens ones in 6 times

**I don't want this to happen when I have unsaved work.**

Comment: When your system seizes up try doing ctrl+alt+f3 or such and drop to the TTY prompt - is there a bunch of error outputon the command line side of things?  Alternatively, ctrl+alt+f3, login, adn check the output of `dmesg -w` to see if there's any major errors triggering actively?

Comment: Is firefox running? I have the problem in Lubuntu with it.